# HTML-Javascript: Concerning an unconventional purpose for a <param /> inside an <object>

Tags: javascript, html, object, parameters

EDIT: I now see where the "value" is programmatically editable for a param, so I'll just pick a param name that should be globally unique and roll with this methodology.

ORIGINAL QUESTION:
Is this purpose for a `<param />` appropriate:

I'm using one `<object>` tag per surveillance camera file listing and need to programmatically store the filestamp displayed in the `<td>` adjacent to the `<td>` of any user-selected .mp4 file name from a TRANSIENT file listing (or "table") DOM style of that `<object>` for use in manipulating the file playing (or "video") DOM style (also transient) in order to time-synchronize multiple `<object>`s playing their .mp4 files from multiple camera views.
A typical `<object>` listing is shown below, but note that this `<object>` is a combined listing of videos, snapshots, and cameras, rather than one of the `<object>`s dedicated to a single camera or file type:[image]
FWIW, I make the timestamps come in a `<td aria-label=[timestamp to show]></td>` so they can't become part of drag and drop operations.

We're talking 5 recorded cameras/views that the user will play back all 5 together as they research recorded activities.  Each .mp4 file is merely a 6 minute segment within a longer timeframe of interest, so I will also have the subsequent .mp4 segments load and play when the previous segment finishes.  FWIW, each `<object>`'s DOM layout is transient at the level I'm talking about here, such that both the filestamp info and the dynamically created event listeners get lost from DOM when the `<object>`'s DOM style goes from `objectID.contentDocument.body.table` to `objectID.contentDocument.body.video`.  In order not to lose the ever-valuable but transient file timestamp info contained in the table style DOM, I am pondering the notion of using dummy `<param />` elements in the `<object>` to pass that otherwise-transient information to the `objectID.contentDocument.body.video` style of the `<object>` for the ultimate purpose that all the playing `<object>`s can stay synchronized to each other as they serial play their .mp4 segments.

I suspect that I am wrong to try passing the data in this way because: *NO LONGER THE CASE: 1) the `<param />`'s appear to be read-only wherever they would be accessed conventionally in the DOM,* and 2) I would risk choosing a `<param />` name already claimed for conventional `<object>` use, and 3) my HTML experience level here is newbie.

Is this purpose for a `<param />` appropriate?  If not, surely there is a better means of grabbing a bit of info from a transient portion of DOM and storing it higher up in a static portion the DOM without doing so in global-level `<script>` variables, right?  IMHO, **By rights, a piece of data like this belongs attached to the `<object>` it pertains to instead of to a global variable.**

Here is one of my `<object>`s, except I'm showing it with `<param>`s presumptuously included:

```
<object id="sysjpgmp4_motion" type="text/html"
  onload="glonload( sysjpgmp4_motion.contentDocument.body.children[0].currentSrc, getElementById('sysjpgmp4_motion'), '', '', '', '', '')"
  onclick="this.data=this.data;"
  data="/camera_snapshots/camera_*/*jpg /var/www/camera_streams/camera_*/*mp4-MOTION"
  width="1700px"
  height="900px"
  style="font-size:15px;overflow:auto;border:5px solid black;border-width:20px 3px 3px;">
  <param name="timestamp" value="initial" />
  <param name="filename" value="initial" />
</object>
```

Here is the `function glonload(...)`:

```
function glonload( currSrc, elid, elname, tagname, arg1, arg2, arg3 )
{
  if (elid.contentDocument.body.children[0] != 'undefined' && elid.contentDocument.body.children[0] != null && elid.contentDocument.body.children[0].localName == 'table')
  {
    if(elid.contentDocument.body.children[0].tBodies[0] == 'undefined' || elid.contentDocument.body.children[0].tBodies[0] == null){alert('Too many event files to list with ' + currSrc + '.  Delete overrunning ones on server.');return}
    elid.contentDocument.body.children[0].tBodies[0].addEventListener("click",function(item)
    {
//The hard-coded 2 pixel corrections below might need to be adjusted for border widths or other style settings the web server might send differently in the future:
       var rowindex=Math.trunc((item.pageY+2)/((elid.contentDocument.body.children[0].tBodies[0].clientHeight+2)/elid.contentDocument.body.children[0].tBodies[0].childElementCount)-.5)
       var filename=elid.contentDocument.body.children[0].tBodies[0].rows[rowindex].cells[1].innerText
       if(elid.contentDocument.body.children[0].tBodies[0].rows[rowindex].cells[1].innerText.endsWith('.mp4'))
       {
           var timestamp=elid.contentDocument.body.children[0].tBodies[0].rows[rowindex].cells[0].outerHTML.substr(18)
           timestamp=timestamp.substring(0,timestamp.indexOf(" ]"))
//THE FOLLOWING LINE IS WHERE I'M ASKING FOR HELP
//         elid.         =timestamp
     //Useful idiot: alert(timestamp)
      }
    })
  }
  else
  {
//Here the currentSource of object is now a loaded (or loading?) jpg or mp4 viewer. 
//Still got that timestamp from the click?   We'll need it here if this is the mp4 so all other objects match the time.  Let's store it in a non-transcient child of the object element somewhere on click.>
//But which way is the most acceptable?
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just choose a globally unique param name and roll with this idea.  In my case with the name being "timestamp", it is accessed programmatically by `elid.children["timestamp"]`, and its value is `elid.children["timestamp"].value` and is editable.